# Shell program to print the first and last parameter and their sum

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to make a shell program which prints out the first and the last parameter, then it prints out their sum. Here is my code, but it gives an error and doesn't work, can anybody help?

```
echo "How many parameters do you want?"
read param
echo "You entered $param parameters"
first = $param
last = `echo $*|cut –f$# -d" "`
sum = `$first + $last`
echo "The sum of the two parameters are $sum"
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach for you:

```
first="$1"
last="${@: -1}"
echo "first: $first"
echo "last: $last"
sum=$((first + last))
echo "The sum of the two parameters are $sum"
```

You can run like this:

```
./program.sh 1 2 3 4                                                                                                                             
first: 1
last: 4
The sum of the two parameters are 5
```